# Query de verificação de data

Tags: query

Tenho uma query normal:

```
select * from TABELAS 
    Where (AlvaraNumero  <>  '0') 
    and ( AlvaraValidade <> '0000-00-00' ) 
    and ( AlvaraAnexo is  NOT Null ) 
    and ( AcidenteNumero <> '0') 
    and ( AcidenteValidade  <>  '0000-00-00' ) 
    and ( AcidenteValidade <> '0000-00-00' ) 
    and ( SeguroNumero <> '0') 
    and ( SeguroValidade <> '0000-00-00') 
    and ( FinancasValidade <> '0000-00-00') 
    and ( FinancasAnexo is NOT Null) 
    and ( SocialValidade <> '0000-00-00') 
    and ( SocialAnexo is NOT Null) 
    and ( RemuneracaoValidade <> '0000-00-00' ) 
    and ( RemuneracaoAnexo is not  Null) 
    and ( InstaladorNumero  <>  '0') 
    and ( InstaladorValidade <> '0000-00-00' ) 
    and ( InstaladorAnexo is Not Null) 
    and ( MedicaValidade <> '0000-00-00') 
    and ( MedicaAnexo is Not Null) 
    order by tb_trabalhador.id asc
```

Como acrescentar a todos os campos que tem Validade no fim pois são datas que não podem ser Nulos nem já terem passado da data de hoje?
Se já tiverem passado a data já não poderão aparecer nesta query.

Comment: Estas a usar alguma linguagem de alto nível ou é mesmo só SQL?

Comment: Estou a utilizar o SQL. O mais simples.

Comment: Não foi dito qual o SGBD, mas : utilize um tipo DATE para as colunas de datas , se o BD tiver utilize CHECK CONSTRAINTS ou TRIGGERS para validações do tipo data menor/maior que a atual , utilize a CONSTRAINT NOT NULL nesre campos obrigatórios.

Comment: MSQL WORKBENCH 6.0

Comment: a resposta abaixo não é suficiente para o que quer? Poderia dar mais detalhes sobre o que não atende?

Answer (score 3):

No exemplo abaixo irá retornar apenas registros com data menor que a data e hora atual.

Em Oracle:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPODATA IS NOT NULL AND CAMPODATA < SYSDATE
```

Em SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPODATA IS NOT NULL AND CAMPODATA < GETDATE()
```

Em DB2:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPODATA IS NOT NULL AND CAMPODATA < (CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
```

Em MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPODATA IS NOT NULL AND CAMPODATA < NOW()
```

Comment: e se usar com MySQL?

Comment: adicionado para MySql. Ficar atento se a data e hora é UTC ou não pois NOW retorna no TimeZone corrente.